# Get several substring from one string

Tags: mysql

I've got table, that contains columns like: `"String"` or `"Another" simple "string"`, etc. I want to make new table, where every word, enclosed in `""`, would be in separate row.

I tried to do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149690/search-for-text-between-delimiters-in-mysql), but the problem is that the amount of the "right" words is different on each line, and they may be located in every plase inside the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's awkward to use SQL to split up strings. In general, SQL treats each scalar value as irreducible. If you try to use SQL expressions to do something different, it feels like you're typing with your feet.

I would not solve this with SQL. I would write a script in PHP or Perl or Python to fetch data out of the database, use the powerful string-manipulation functions provides by my scripting language, and then insert the result into the database.

---

Re your comment:

The only purely MySQL solution I can think of is to write a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines.html) that contains a WHILE loop, iteratively pulling out quoted words and reducing the string until there are no quoted words left in it.

In other words, this loop approach would look like the following *pseudocode*:

```
WHILE LOCATE('"', STRING) > 0
    SET WORD := SUBSTRING_INDEX(...)
    INSERT INTO OTHER_TABLE VALUES (WORD)
    SET STRING := REPLACE(STRING, '"WORD"', '')
END
```

Each of these operations is possible with MySQL functions.

- You can test a string to see if it contains quotes:

  ```
  mysql> select locate('"', 'the "quoted" word');
  +-------------------------------------+
  | locate('"', 'the "quoted" word', 1) |
  +-------------------------------------+
  |                                   5 |
  +-------------------------------------+
  ```
- You can find the first quoted word from a string:

  ```
  mysql> select substring_index(substring_index('the "quoted" word', '"', 2), '"', -1);
  +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | substring_index(substring_index('the "quoted" word', '"', 2), '"', -1) |
  +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | quoted                                                                 |
  +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```
- You can remove a quoted word from a string:

  ```
  mysql> select replace('the "quoted" word', concat('"', 'quoted', '"'), '');
  +--------------------------------------------------------------+
  | replace('the "quoted" word', concat('"', 'quoted', '"'), '') |
  +--------------------------------------------------------------+
  | the  word                                                    |
  +--------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```

I'll leave the final procedure coding to you.

Comment: I realize, that there are a lot of ways to do this much faster and easier, but I've got Windows based machine with MySQl and nothing more. Security policy...